# Azure pipeline skips scheduled job

Tags: azure-devops, conditional-statements, azure-pipelines, scheduled-tasks, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a very simple **pipeline** that has a **1 stage** and **1 job** that **prints** `Hello World`.

I would like the stage to be **triggered based only on the schedule** (not when I push).

```
schedules:
- cron: "*/5 * * * *"
  displayName: Run every 5 Mins
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true  

stages:
- stage: BatchRun
  displayName: Batch Run
  condition: and(always(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))
  jobs:
  - job: Echo
    steps:
    - script: 'Hello World'
```

Currently, there are 2 problems

1. The stage is triggered when I push.
2. the job is skipped with a message `The job was skipped.` I have no information as to why.

I have tried with different condition `eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')`

I have also tried having another stage before the stage with the condition.

```
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage A!
```

I have looked at Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: I am guessing the skipping is due to ADO not recognizing the run as a schedule since it is going off of every push it sounds like.  Is the branch you are pushing to master or a different one?

Comment: @DreadFrost is on master, is there any way to check (logs) or another way if the job is recognized as scheduled?

Comment: Your pipeline is looking for `main` if you want to check after the pipeline has been ran click the hamburger menue and download logs. There is an azure-pipelines.expanded.yaml file

Comment: I'm facepalming myself, the copy and paste side effect, just corrected it and my second stage now is running, will wait and see if it will run again in 5 mins. Also will check what happens when I have another commit, thanks. Will update here later.

Comment: I've had this same issue with my pipelines after the default was switched from `master` to `main` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was

```
trigger: none

schedules:
- cron: "*/5 * * * *"
  displayName: Run every 5 Mins
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true  

stages:
- stage: BatchRun
  displayName: Batch Run
  jobs:
  - job: Echo
    steps:
    - script: 'echo "Hello World"'
```

1. To add `trigger: none` as @psfinaki mentioned so the job does not run by on commit
2. Since in this example I have only one stage, I removed the `condition` alltogether. If there are multiple stages, those cane be targeted then with conditions.

Answer (score 1):

To make the pipeline not trigger with push, add `trigger: none`. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#opting-out-of-ci).

As for the job skipped, you seem to have found the answer, but for reference, such things can happen when [GUI settings override YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), something to watch out for.